# Running pytest in-process

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to run [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) in-process instead of in the command line?

This exists on nosetests: `import nose; nose.run(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With Pytest 2.0 you can](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code):

```
import pytest
pytest.main()
```